# Is it grammatically right using bare infinitives leading infinitive phrases?

Tags: grammar

I've seen a TV series in which a native English speaker always uses bare infinitives leading infinitive phrases, such as:

> The only thing you can do is find a place and watch.

Is it an incorrect verbal usage?

Comment: This is not the simple present tense. **Find** and **watch** are bare infinitives, and they are used correctly. @Colin Fine, thank you for pointing out my clumsiness

Comment: @JeffreyCarney Thank you for explaining, however is it a legal use of bare infinitives grammatically?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly correct and natural in conversation and writing contexts.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney However I just haven't seen any info mentioning it, the usages of bare infinitives are all about following verbs as auxiliaries and "had better", none of it notes the usage of leading infinitive phrases.

[One of the grammar explanations](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/)

Comment: The verb **do** is being used as a substitute for **find** and **watch**. So in a sense, they follow the modal auxiliary **can**, which is why the bare infinitive is required.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney Thank you so so much for explaining, got it all now! If you don't mind, I still have one more sentence that I don't understand, and somehow nobody is answering it, may I ask your help once more if it's not bothering? Thank you again!